# IndexedDB over local HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I would like to develop an application which uses a browser to interact with the user. The application is to be available offline and distributable via a zip.

The functions I would like to perform are to be handled by HTML, CSS, JS and I would like to make use of the IndexedDB functionality.

I have hit a problem with IndexedDB (Chrome) in that the same code works in an online space but not from a local hard drive location (file://).

Refer to example: http://jsfiddle.net/FwuUD/

```
(function() {

    var db;
    var dbreq = indexedDB.open("TestApp", 2);

    dbreq.onsuccess = function(e) {
        alert("Database created");
        db = e.target.result;

        var employeeStore = db.createObjectStore (
            "employees",
            {keyPath: "id"}
        );

    };

    dbreq.onerror = function(e) {
        alert("Database Error: " + e.target.errorCode);
    };

    dbreq.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
        alert("Database upgrade needed");
    };

})();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This works okay for me in both cases, but I had to move the `createObjectStore` to `onupgradeneeded`

Comment: If you have python: "python -m http.server" starts a web server on port 8000 in the local directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexedDB API only works inside a webserver. When you navigate to it using the file system it won't work. The indexedDB API needs a domain context to work in and the file system doesn't provide that. Short you need an url to use the api.

Comment: great thanks for your help, do you have any suggestions on how I can utilize this functionality in a client side only app?

Comment: That should mean that every device you want to copy it on must have a web server running. Also the files would have to be copied in a folder of that webserver so it is accessible trough the loopback URL (http://127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is looking for an updated answer to this 6-year-old question, both Chrome and Safari allow local HTML files to access IndexedDB API now, without the need for a local server. [IE continues to hold out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50996302/401329) on this it seems. Unsure about Edge or Firefox.

Comment: Please, can you extend this answer and specify how to make Chrome allow access to indexDB API with local HTML and JS files? I'm trying to but it doesn't work. It seems to be locked out. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

IndexedDB is disabled when run from file:/// for security. It's unclear if you control the browser parameters. If you do, you can pass --allow-file-access-from-files which will allow IndexedDB to work from the file:/// origin.