# Can HTAs use HTML5 IndexedDB?

Tags: html, hta

I'm having no luck using IndexedDB with HTAs nor finding any information on the feasibility of doing so.  Can hypertext applications (HTAs) use the IndexedDB feature of HTML 5?

Comment: Try adding this line: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/css) it's not possible. Though you could try with an `iframe` loaded from a server... @JeremyJStarcher Adding the HTML5 doctype and/or x-ua meta alone can't do this (tested), also Indexed Database API wasn't implemented in IEs until IE10...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer is no, any attempt to do so will yield:

```
DOM7005: Indexed DB is only available on websites with http or https URL schemes.
```

This topic is similar to: [Can local files in IE10 use IndexedDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287134/can-local-files-in-ie10-use-indexeddb)

However, as you're using `HTA` you have access to other database COM ActiveX objects, such as `ADODB.Connection`. To get you started, here's a short snippet that creates a SQLCE 3.5 database and opens it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
  var adox = new ActiveXObject("ADOX.Catalog");
  adox.Create("Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=sample.sdf");
  var db = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
  db.Open("Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=sample.sdf");
  db.Close();
} catch (e) {
  alert("Exception: " + e.message);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```