# indexedDB w/r to same origin and local files

Tags: indexeddb, same-origin-policy

My question is concerned only with Firefox and Chrome.  I've been working with indexedDB in local html files for an offline portion of an application.  [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694334/indexeddb-over-local-html-file) of the stackoverflow questions on this topic are quite old and state that a local html file can't have an indexedDB database but it seems to be permitted now because it is working.

This [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Misc_top_level/Same-origin_policy_for_file:_URIs) on the same-origin policy for local files is quite helpful, and I'd like to understand how it relates to accessing indexedDB databases in local html pages.

The set up that I'm interested in involves two local html files, one in a subdirectory relative to the other.  Please let one be called M and the other S, indicating the one in the subdirectory.  The documentation states, and I've tried it out, that M can open S but S cannot open M.  I've been able to open S in an iframe contained in M (and scripts in S run); but the reverse is not true.

My four questions are:

1. Is it guaranteed that M and S can each have separate indexedDB databases, such that more total storage space can be accessed through having two local html pages instead of one?
2. In this two-page scenario, can M read and write data to an indexedDB database in S, but S won't be able to read/write data into the database of M?
3. Can the origin of S be changed to that of M using an equivalent of `document.domain` as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Changing_origin) but for local pages? (It appears that document.domain is null for local pages.) If so, will S be able to access the database of M or will both M and S together be allocated only one indexedDB database since they now have the same origin?
4. If it is possible, now, for M and S to each have a separate database and for M and S to each read/write data to the other's database, is this permission likely to remain in Firefox and Chrome? The IE browser, and I assume Edge, appear to not permit a local html page to have any form of local storage.  Yet, the use of PWAs appears to make this type of storage necessaary.  Is the IE model outdated or does this work in Firefox now as a loop hole that will eventually be closed?

Thank you.